# How to combine multiple String generated from for loop into one variable?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("How many items will be supplied by this supplier?");
SPItemAmount = SupplierEntry.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ok, your item ID with this supplier is:");
for(int i = 1;i <= SPItemAmount; i++) {
    System.out.println("I" + i);
}

public String getSupplierDetails() {
    return "SP" + AddSupplier.getSupplierID() + SPName+
}
```

My ItemID will be generated based on the user input. When comes to the getSupplierDetails, how am i going to print all the ItemID with one variable? Or there is another way? Appreciate for help.

Comment: StringBuilder is what i guess you are looking for.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between printing stuff on the screen, and returning something from a method. You need the latter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: Please stick to **naming conventions**. Method and variable names should start with a **lowercase** character and classes with **uppercase**. So it should be `sPItemAmount`, `supplierEntry`, `addSupplier` and `sPName` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is rather straightforward with the problem at hand, when you ask a question you should supply as much pertinent code as possible. This will remove a lot of guessing and assumptions. At least provide code that will compile.

One way you can do is to fill (append to) a string variable for every iteration of your **for** loop (see the **getSupplierID()** method below). Although not mandatory, allow your methods to accept parameters so that variables don't need to be class global.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner supplierEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get supplier name...
    String sPName = "";
    // Continue to ask for Supplier Name if validation fails.
    while(sPName.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("What is the Supplier's Name (c to cancel):");
        sPName = supplierEntry.nextLine().trim();
        // Privide a Quit option.
        if (sPName.toLowerCase().equals("c")) {
            System.out.println("User Quit!");
            System.exit(0); // Close the application.
        }
        // Supplier Name validation...
        if (sPName.equals("")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Supplier Name Provided! Try again.\n");
        }
    }

    // Get number of items supplied by supplier...
    int sPItemAmount = 0;
    // Continue to ask for Items Count if validation fails.
    while (sPItemAmount == 0) {
        System.out.println("How many items will be supplied by " + sPName + "?");
        // Trap exception for Numerical validation...
        try {
            sPItemAmount = supplierEntry.nextInt();
        } catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Items Amount Provided! " + 
                               "Whole Numbers Only! Try again.\n");
        }
        supplierEntry.nextLine(); // Clear scanner buffer
    }

    // Generate the Supplier ID
    String supplierID = getSupplierID(sPItemAmount);
    // Get Supplier Details.
    String supplierDetails = getSupplierDetails(sPName, supplierID);

    // Display information...
    System.out.println("Ok, your item ID with " + sPName + " is: " + supplierID);    
    System.out.println("Supplier Details Are: " + supplierDetails); 

    // Close the Scanner object.
    supplierEntry.close();  
}

public static String getSupplierID(int itemAmount) {
    String itemID = "";
    for(int i = 1; i <= itemAmount; i++) {
        itemID+= "I" + i;
        // which is the same as:
        // itemID = itemID + "I" + i;
    }
    return itemID;
}     

public static String getSupplierDetails(String supplName, String itemID) {
    // Replace any whitespaces in Supplier Name with
    // the underscore character ( _ ). You can remove 
    // the .replace() method if you don't want this.
    return "SP" + itemID + supplName.replace(" ", "_");
}
```